# Use different enum values during unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, enums, business-rules

I wrote a handler that takes essentially three pieces of info on an error: What app it came from; the exception's stack trace; and the exception's error message.  Based on that information I employ business rules, set up per application in the database, to categorize each error.

For my unit testing, I needed to be able to control the business rules for an application so I could properly predict the category.  Since the source application parameter is an enum, I tacked on a TestApp value into that enum and used that in all my ut's.

Now that we're going into release, my code reviewer rightly wants me to remove the TestApp from the enum.  Obviously this would break my unit test compile.  If I change the TestApp to a real one, now I can compile but my tests will mostly fail because the business rules for the real app are different (and likely to change).

Here is a simplified example of what I'm talking about:

```
void Main()
{
    var fooError = new MyError
    {
        Application = Application.TestApp1,
        ErrorMessage = "my error message here",
        ErrorTime = DateTime.Now,
        StackTrace = "stack trace here",
        User = "mike"
    };

    Console.WriteLine("That error is of category {0}.", BusinessLogicForErrors(fooError));
}

string BusinessLogicForErrors(MyError error)
{
    string errCat;
    if (error.Application == Application.RealApp)
        errCat = "Horrible";
    else
        errCat = "Not So Bad";

    return errCat;
}

enum Application 
{
    RealApp,
    TestApp1,
    TestApp2
}

class MyError 
{
   public Application Application; 
   public DateTime ErrorTime;
   public string ErrorMessage;
   public string StackTrace;
   public string User;
}
```

I suppose I could strip out the Application enum and use a string instead, I just want to do it for the right reasons.  Also this probably qualifies more as an integration test than a unit test, so maybe that was a mistake (or should be using mocks).

What should I do to fix this problem?  What should I have done from the outset to avoid it?

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a mocking framework.

Comment: I agree and have been looking into Moq a little bit, but I've never mocked an enum before, just classes.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you mock the enum. More like you mock the app so it ignores the enum and just uses a known set of business rules. It's hard to be more specific without any example code to go on.

Comment: Added a code sample @MatthewStrawbridge

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer just now, but I'd think about dropping the enum and using the Strategy Pattern instead (e.g. `HorribleStrategy`, `NotSoBadStrategy`). That way you can test the strategies in isolation and assign strategies to apps (including your test app) at runtime.

Comment: Thanks I will look into that pattern.  At the moment the way I'm dealing with it is I created a new Build Configuration, and in that config I define a precompile constant TESTING.  Then in the enum I surround the test values with #if TESTING ... #endif.  Then in the other build configs I also do NOT build the unit test project.